# Leaflet going off OSM map route while switching tabs

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, osrm

I have a problem painting a track on OSM map using leaflet.

I'm getting a track array of geo-locations from my OSRM service, and painting the track live by tracking a a device who's driving at received track.

usually everything work as excepted but sometimes usually while switching tabs on the browser leaflet paint polyline one the map except for the track it self, as you can see in the picture:
[image]

my paint route function:

```
paintRoute(route) {
    if (!route) {
        return;
    }
    let coordinates = DirectionService.toLatLngArray(route);
    if (coordinates && coordinates.length > 1) {
        let delay = Math.round(7000 / coordinates.length);
        this._driverMarker.resetAndSetLatLng([coordinates[0][0], coordinates[0][1]], delay);
        for (let i = 1; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
            this._driverMarker.addLatLng(coordinates[i], delay);
        }
        this.setZoomByRouteTotalDistace(route.map(r => r.distance).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
        this._driverMarker.start();
    }
}
```

in order to move the marker I'm using https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker

any suggestions how to handle the problem?
Thank you

Comment: I had a similar problem, I switched to a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: @FalkeDesign thank you, I'll give it a try. 
hopefully that won't be a complicated change